# View Cart Not Displaying Cart Contents

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I use my own custom theme, the "View Cart" link shows me the cart page, but it's blank.

If I switch to the TwentySixteen theme, it works fine. What do I have to change in my theme to make it work?

Here is the link to my Woocommerce shop: http://educanimal.com/en/shop/

Comment: Double check that your [WooCommerce pages](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-pages/) are correctly installed. And make sure that you cart page has the proper shortcode: `[woocommerce_cart]`

Answer (score 0):

I changed the template for the cart and checkout pages and it works fine now. As long as this workaround works, I'm happy.